# Are function names considered as variables in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, variables

Just a quick and easy question which has been confusing me a lot, are function names like:

```
function drive() {
```

which are function names considered as variables, is drive considered as a variable?

Comment: If you have a function called `drive` - and then create a variable called `drive` - what happens?

Comment: @tymeJV well the first thing is you have a bad design or coding standards in that case haha.

Comment: `function msg() { alert('oy'); };msg();var msg = function() { alert('vey'); };msg();`

Answer (score 1):

Function declarations create a variable in the current scope which has the same name as the function and the value of which is the function.

Named function expressions create such a variable *in their own scope* (not the current scope).

Anonymous function expressions and arrow functions do not create variables.

Answer (score 1):

yes.

`drive` will be a variable whose value is a named function with the same name. The compiler declares the variable for you, gives it a named function as the value of it -and with the same name as the variable-, and also [hoists](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting) the variable.

This is done by the compiler as you [declare a function](https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/07/06/function-declarations-vs-function-expressions/).

So, as with any other variable, you can rewrite it:

```
function bar(){
    return 'bar';
}

bar = function(){
    return 'foo';
}

console.log(bar() );//foo
```

However, due to hoisting, changing the order doesn't changes the result:

```
bar = function(){
    return 'foo';
}
function bar(){
    return 'bar';
}


console.log(bar() );//also foo
```

Which doesn't mean that the `function bar()...` block isn't creating a `bar` variable, but just that it is created before the `bar = function...` statement.

You can prevent the compiler to create the variable just by wrapping the function declaration with `()`:

```
( function bar(){
    return 'foo';
});

bar(); //error
```

Which is really common to launch [IIFEs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression):

```
( function bar(){
    alert('foo');
})();
//this will launch the alert in a browser.
```